# When is the pullback of a tangent bundle along a curve a tangent bundle on the curve?

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider a smooth manifold $M$; and it's tangent bundle $TM \rightarrow M$; suppose we have curve $c:I \rightarrow M$

When is the pullback $c^*TM$ diffeomorphic to the tangent bundle $Tc$ on $c$?

**edit**

The answer is always, as the comment beneath by Mike Miller usefully points out.

What happens if instead of a curve it is the circle $S^1$, or more generally any manifold?

Comment: By dimensional consideration $\dim M = 1$.

Comment: @miller: ok, thanks for the tip; I'll change it.

Comment: @Mike There are many various non-isomorphic bundles on a curve, say trivial bundles $I \times \mathbb{R}^k$ of the ranks $k = 1,2,\dots$. In fact, since the segment $I$ is contractible, there are only trivial bundles on $I$. I guess this is what you mean.

Comment: @YuriVyatkin My comment is nonsense, because as you point out, $1 \neq n$ for most integers $n$. Thanks for pointing this out. I've deleted it. Clearly it's time for me to go to bed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **never**, if the dimension of $M$ is greater than $2$, because the rank of the pullback bundle will be equal to the dimension of $M$, and the rank of the tangent bundle of $c$ is $1$.